# How to change background image in android application?

Tags: android

There is a background in my app, and it should be changed after some event. So, how should i do that?

main.xml:

```
    <AbsoluteLayout
android:id="@+id/widget0"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/bg">
```

and there background should be changed:

```
if(a<b) *change background to bg2.jpg goes here*
```

help please and sorry for my english

Comment: It is strongly not recommended to use AbsoluteLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you use Absolute Layout. So just instantiate new AbsoluteLayout object.

```
AbsoluteLayout al = (AbsoluteLayout) findViewById(R.id.widget0);
//This function will change background drawable, so place it where you want.
al.setBackgroundDrawable(yourDrawableID);
```

By the way, you can also do

```
al.setBackgroundResource(resourceID);
```

with resourceID should navigate to a drawable ID and set to 0 if you want to remove the background.

Comment: The type AbsoluteLayout is deprecated. What should i do to avoid this error?

Comment: It's deprecated to ensure that Android app is compatible with many screen resolution. If you really want to use AbsoluteLayout, ensure that compatible. Why do you need AbsoluteLayout? If you need to place control at a specific position, it's a way to do that in RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1):

its simple,         `android:background="@drawable/YourImage"`

Comment: you should write the code in the layout tag of your XML file.